# Javascript Adding two input values together and displaying answer in third when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add 2 values together and display answer in 3rd textbox however I keep getting NAN in the 3rd text box. Any help ? Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <form name="Calcultor"  Method="Get" id='form1'>
         First Number: <input type="text" name="fnum" size="35" id="first"> + Second Number: <input type="text" name="snum" size="35" id="sec"><br>
         <br>
               Answer:<input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />  <button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
    </form>

    <script lang="javascript">
        function Calculate()
        {
          var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
          var last = document.getElementById('sec').value; 

           document.getElementById('ans').value=parseInt(first) + parseInt(sec);
           document.form1.submit();
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: you should accept the answer which satisfies you the most, to encourage users to help you in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong variable name by using "sec" instead of "last"

You are storing the value in "last"

```
var last = document.getElementById('sec').value;
```

And accessing as `parseInt(sec)`. As sec is not defined anywhere in your script the value of sec becomes `undefined` you and thus are getting NaN.

Here is the correct code,

```
function Calculate()
        {
          var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
          var last = document.getElementById('sec').value; 

           document.getElementById('ans').value=parseInt(first) + parseInt(last);
           document.form1.submit();
        }
```

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/www1fxjb/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo -- you add `sec` but really want `last`:

`document.getElementById('ans').value=parseInt(first) + parseInt(last);`